# How can I set and append in column with conditional case in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to run this sql query in Django

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `COLUMN` = (CASE WHEN `COLUMN` = "" THEN '100' ELSE CONCAT(`COLUMN`,'100') END)
WHERE `SOMEID` IN [id1,id2,id3];
```

I tried this

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F
Table.objects.filter(someid__in=[id1,id2,id3]).
update(column=
  Case(
    When(column="",then="100"),
    default= column + "100",
  )
)
```

I dont know how to put concat in default here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`F` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F

Table.objects.filter(...).update(column=F("column") + "100")
```

You don't need to check if `column == ""` because it won't matter when you append `"100"` to it.